# My Jframe wont stay open when button is clicked

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe, jbutton

I have and edit button and its supposed to open a different Jframe but for some reason it flashes on screen and goes away. I cant figure it out maybe you guys can. And my delete button deletes the row above the row selected. the frame is at like 250 and the button pressed is on line 323

```
Button declaration:
      btnAdd = new JButton("Add Student");
      btnAdd.addActionListener(bh);
      btnEdit = new JButton("EDIT");
      btnEdit.addActionListener(bh);
      btnEdit.setEnabled(false); 
      btnDelete = new JButton("DELETE");
      btnDelete.addActionListener(bh);
      btnDelete.setEnabled(false);
      btnSort = new JButton("Update");
      btnSort.addActionListener(bh);
      btnSave = new JButton("SAVE");
      btnSave.addActionListener(bh);
      btnSave.setActionCommand("Save");
      btnAddInput = new JButton("Add Student");
      btnAddInput.addActionListener(bh);
      btnAddInput.setActionCommand("AddInput");
      btnCancel = new JButton("Cancel");
      btnCancel.addActionListener(bh);
```

Frame declaration:

```
      frame1 = new JFrame("Edit Student");
      frame1.setVisible(false);
      frame1.setResizable(false);
      frame1.setDefaultCloseOperation(HIDE_ON_CLOSE);
      frame1.add(addPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
      frame1.add(buttonPanel2, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
      frame1.pack();
```

Button Handler:
          class ButtonHandler implements ActionListener {
          public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

```
               if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Add Student")) {
               txtID.setText("");
               txtName.setText("");
               txtMajor.setText("");
               txtGPA.setText("");
               txtCampus.setText("");
               txtAddress.setText("");
               txtPhone.setText("");
               txtEmail.setText("");
               txtCurrent.setText("");
               txtPast.setText("");
               txtFuture.setText("");
               txtNotes.setText("");


               frame1.setTitle("Add Student data"); // title bar name for add
               frame1.setVisible(true);
               Student student = new Student(txtID.getText(), txtName.getName(), txtMajor.getText(), txtGPA.getText(), txtCampus.getText(), txtAddress.getText(), txtPhone.getText(),txtEmail.getText(), txtCurrent.getText(), txtPast.getText(), txtFuture.getText(), txtNotes.getText());
               al.add(student);
              try {
                  Student.saveSerialized(student, txtID.getText());
              } catch (IOException ex) {
                  Logger.getLogger(IAdvise.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
              }
               } else if (e.getActionCommand().equals("EDIT")) {
               frame1.setVisible(true); 
               txtID.setText(data[rowIndex][0] + ""); 
               txtName.setText(data[rowIndex][1] + ""); 
               txtMajor.setText(data[rowIndex][2] + "");
               txtGPA.setText(data[rowIndex][3] + "");
               txtCampus.setText(data[rowIndex][4] + "");
               txtAddress.setText(data[rowIndex][5] + "");
               txtPhone.setText(data[rowIndex][6] + "");
               txtEmail.setText(data[rowIndex][7] + "");
               txtCurrent.setText(data[rowIndex][8] + "");
               txtPast.setText(data[rowIndex][9] + "");
               txtFuture.setText(data[rowIndex][10] + "");
               txtNotes.setText(data[rowIndex][11] + "");
               txtID.setEditable(false); 
               frame1.setTitle("Enter Student data"); 
               btnAddInput.setActionCommand("Edit2");
               btnAddInput.setText("ACCEPT");


            } else if (e.getActionCommand().equals("DELETE")) {
               int confirm = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(frame, "ARE YOU SURE?", "CONFIRM",
                        JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);

               if (confirm == 0) {
                  rowIndex = table.getSelectedRow();
                  rowNumber = 0;

                  noOfStudents--;
                  for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
                     if (rowIndex != i && i <= noOfStudents) {
                        data[rowNumber][0] = data[i][0];
                        data[rowNumber][1] = data[i][1];
                        data[rowNumber][2] = data[i][2];
                        data[rowNumber][3] = data[i][3];
                        data[rowNumber][4] = data[i][4];
                        data[rowNumber][5] = data[i][5];
                        data[rowNumber][6] = data[i][6];
                        data[rowNumber][7] = data[i][7];
                        data[rowNumber][8] = data[i][8];
                        data[rowNumber][9] = data[i][9];
                        data[rowNumber][10] = data[i][10];
                        data[rowNumber][11] = data[i][11];


                        rowNumber++;
                     } else if (rowIndex != i && i > noOfStudents) {
                        data[rowNumber][0] = "";
                        data[rowNumber][1] = "";
                        data[rowNumber][2] = "";
                        data[rowNumber][3] = "";
                        data[rowNumber][4] = "";
                        data[rowNumber][5] = "";
                        data[rowNumber][6] = "";
                        data[rowNumber][7] = "";
                        data[rowNumber][8] = "";
                        data[rowNumber][9] = "";
                        data[rowNumber][10] = "";
                        data[rowNumber][11] = "";

                        rowNumber++;
                     }
                  }
                  if (noOfStudents == 1000) {
                       btnAdd.setEnabled(false);
                   }
                  else {
                       btnAdd.setEnabled(true);
                   }
                  if (noOfStudents == 0) {
                     btnDelete.setEnabled(false);
                     btnEdit.setEnabled(false);
                  } else {
                     btnDelete.setEnabled(true);
                     btnEdit.setEnabled(true);
                  }

                  rowIndex = table.getSelectedRow();
                  if (data[rowIndex][0] == null || data[rowIndex][0] == "") {
                     btnEdit.setEnabled(false);
                     btnDelete.setEnabled(false);
                  } else {
                     btnEdit.setEnabled(true);
                     btnDelete.setEnabled(true);
                  }

                  table.updateUI();

               }
```

Comment: Please trim down your code example. Also witch button are you referring too.

Comment: the "Edit" button and sorry im new

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, when you call `setVisible` on a frame, the code will continue running without stopping.

What this is leading to is...

```
frame1.setVisible(true);
.
.
.
frame1.dispose();
```

Basically, you make the frame visible, but later in your code, you dispose of it.

What you really want is a modal dialog which, when made visible, will block the code execution until it is closed.

Take a look at [How to make dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) for more details

**Review...**

Don't extend `PlainDocument` to perform filtering of fields, instead, use a `DocumentFilter`. Take a look at [Text Component Features](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html) and [MDP's Weblog](http://www.jroller.com/dpmihai/entry/documentfilter)

Don't use `KeyListener` on text fields to performing filter, instead, use a `DocumentFilter`

Don't call `JTable.updateUI`.  This has nothing to do with updating the UI when it's contents changed and is used to update the look and feel if it changes.  Instead, rely on the `TableModel` and raise appropriate events to tell the table to update itself

Reduce the complexity of your `actionPerformed` method.  Try breaking the logic down into separate methods, maybe even separate `ActionListener`s or if you really want to try something modular and advanced, take a look at [How to use Actions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html)

Comment: +1, you type a lot faster than me. I was busy typing all those points.

Comment: @camickr It's been a while since I've beaten you to punch ;)

Answer (score 0):

I did something like you and the result is same with you ,so I can give you a method to take it,
you can get a method to print the look,and frame.setVible(true) can be make to called by a method,
create more frame,and when you want to update or repaint it,you can call a method.
  I hope what I says can be make some help to you .